# Numerical precision problem

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, numerical-value

I have this simple code:

```
ep = 1 - 80000000000 (-(199999/200000) + 1/E^(1/200000))

ep // N
```

> -8.27404*10^-8

```
N[ep, MachinePrecision]
```

> -8.27404*10^-8

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, ep // N]
```

> -8.27404*10^-8

All these results are incorrect, since in fact ep>0; they also seem to contradict the following: Quoting from the Mathematica
tutorial ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers:

> [...] the Wolfram Language keeps track of which digits in your result
>   could be affected by unknown digits in your input. It sets the
>   precision of your result so that no affected digits are ever included.
>   This procedure ensures that all digits returned by the Wolfram
>   Language are correct, whatever the values of the unknown digits may
>   be.

```
N[ep, 10]
```

> 1.666664583*10^-6

This seems to be correct.

---

What is wrong in my understanding or in Mathematica's behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MachinePrecision` is really the precision of the machine; the machine itself cannot track precision like Mathematica's arbitrary precision numbers that you get with, say, `N[#,10]&`. The machine performs computations with 2 extra bits or so and rounds afterwards. This is also why raising `$MaxExtraPrecision` has no effect: With `N` you call for machine precision. People who do a lot of numerics actually *want* that because machine precision computations are much faster than arbitrary precision computations.

So, in a nutshell, the snippet that you cited holds only true for arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: Thank you, this clears it for me.

Comment: You're welcome. =)